# How to render Lattice all shape keys to images using python?

Tags: python, scripting

I have created many shape key in lattice which i pin one shape key at a time and render it and save it as a image. How do i iterate through shape keys of lattice and render them to PNG file.

Answer (score 1):

Select  lattice object and run script. Iterates thru each shapekey
and renders to "Key:" plus shapekey name dot png to the directory of your render filepath.  Make sure this is set, on linux this is commonly `/tmp`.

```
import bpy
from os import path

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
lattice = context.object
fp = path.dirname(path.abspath(scene.render.filepath))
key_blocks = lattice.data.shape_keys.key_blocks
lattice.show_only_shape_key = True
for i, kb in enumerate(key_blocks):
    lattice.active_shape_key_index = i
    scene.render.filepath = path.join(fp, "Key:%s.png" % kb.name)
    bpy.ops.render.opengl(write_still=True)
scene.render.filepath = fp
```

Used `render.opengl` for testing purposes.  Change to `render.render` if desired.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to set key frames on your shape keys.
To do this set your frame, and then hover your mouse over the shape key slider and hit the <kbd>i</kbd> key.

To render out as PNG, set your render output to PNG.
This will spit out an image per frame.

If you would like to automate some of the shape key "actions", I would recommend creating actions in the "Dope Sheet" by setting the dropdown in the dopesheet to Action Editor.  Once you have your "New" action created use the timeline in this view to add your keyframes onto your shape keys to create your particular "action".

Once you get through doing this, you can move to the NLA editor, and sequence all of your animated actions. Meaning you can string them together one right after the other.

Comment: thank you. I am wondering if this is too cumbersome so looking for a script method to access shape keys and pin it one sha[e key at a time and render the image.